# ActionScript ByteArray manipulation

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, binary, arrays

I have some binary data and I can't store it in a string, as such I'm using a ByteArray.
The problem is that I need some functionality that comes with strings, to be specific I need the charAt, substr, indexOf and substring methods.

Comment: Chris: can you add a little description of what you are writing to the bytearray? I think you will need to know what the format is of the byte array to make it searchable in the way you describe. For example: is it a single AMF object? Or is it several strings? or an object a string and something else?

Comment: The byte array contains the result of php's serialize() function. The data before it was serialized was like this: Array(byte opcode, array(data, data, ...)) [Note: the contents of the nested array can be arbitrary 8bit binary data, as such the serialized output also contains 8bit arbitrary binary data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These would be fairly easy to implement. I can post the code if wanted. Is the data string-like? Or does it need to be treated as arbitrary binary? In either case, how wide are characters (e.g. 8-bit, 16-bit)?

```
public static function charAt(bytes:ByteArray, index:int):String {
    if (bytes.length <= index) return null; 
    return String.fromCharCode(bytes[index]); 
} 

public static function substr(bytes:ByteArray, start:int, length:int=0):String { 
    var res:ByteArray = bytes.readBytes(bytes, start, length); 
    return res.toString(); 
} 

public static function substring(bytes:ByteArray, start:int, end:int=0):String { 
    return substr(bytes, start, end-start); 
}

public static function indexOf(bytes:ByteArray, str:String):int { 
    for (var i:int=0; i<bytes.length; i++) { 
        var strPos:int = 0; 
        while (String.fromCharCode(bytes[i+strPos]) == str.charAt(strPos)) { 
            strPos++; 
            if (strPos == str.length) return i; 
        } 
    } 
    return -1; 
}
```

Comment: The data **contains** arbitrary binary, so I guess the entire thing should be treated as arbitrary data, the characters are 8bits wide.

Comment: One other question -- should these methods return Strings, or new ByteArrays?

Comment: `public static function charAt(bytes:ByteArray, index:int):String
{
  if (bytes.length <= index) return null;
  return String.fromCharCode(bytes[index]);
}
   
public static function substr(bytes:ByteArray, start:int, length:int=0):String
{
  var res:ByteArray = bytes.readBytes(bytes, start, length);
  return res.toString();
}
   
public static function substring(bytes:ByteArray, start:int, end:int=0):String
{
  return substr(bytes, start, end-start);
}
`

Comment: `public static function indexOf(bytes:ByteArray, str:String):int 
{
  for (var i:int=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
    var strPos:int = 0;
    while (String.fromCharCode(bytes[i+strPos]) == str.charAt(strPos)) {
      strPos++;
      if (strPos == str.length)
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}`

Comment: Thanks your help is deeply appreciated. If you ever need any php help contact me.

Comment: One more question, is there a way to make your substring function produce a bytearray instead of a string?

Comment: my substring just calls my substr, which as you can see calls toString() on the byte array. should be simple to have versions that return the byte array instead.

Comment: Yes correct, I thought it called a function "substring" at first, thanks for all your help!